# Convert int into a character in a user defined function

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner at C++. I simply want to output the letter grade next to the numerical grade but I don't know how to convert the int W to output the letter.

```
char Grade(int W)
{
    char A,B,C,F;
    if (W == 100)
        return W = "A";
    else if (W == 99)
        return A;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to convert W?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the different `types` that exist in a C++ program. `int` is for numbers, `char` is for characters.

Also, there is a difference between the **type**, the **name** and the **value** of a variable.
The declarations

```
char A,B,C,F;
```

mean that you are creating 4 `char` variables. Their **names** are A, B, C and F. But right now they don't contain any **values**. So you can change your code to:

```
char Grade(int W)
{
 char A = 'A',B = 'B',C = 'C',F = 'F';  //now, A has the value 'A', B has the value 'B' etc.
 if(W==100)
     return A;
 else if(W==99)
     return A;
}
```

Now, the variable `A`, which is a `char` variable, has the value `'A'`. Also, please note that the type that you return must be the same as the **return type** of your function.
Your function has the **signature** `char Grade(int W)`, which means the **argument** is an `int` and the **return type** is `char`.

Now what do you do if there are 100 different possible values for `W`? You don't want to be checking for each possibility. Otherwise you will end up with 100 different `else if` ... statements, which defeats the purpose of programming! Instead, you want everything that's above 90 to be 'A', everything else above 80 to be 'B', etc. So your code changes to:

```
char Grade(int W)
{
 char A = 'A',B = 'B',C = 'C',F = 'F';
 if(W >= 90)     //Now, any value of W that is greater than
                 //or equal to 90 will return 'A'
     return A;
 else if(W >= 80) //the 'else' means that (W >= 90) was not true,
                      //so W must be less than 90. Now we check if W >= 80
     return B;
 else if ..... //do the same for C, F etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a score into a letter grade with a simple if/else block.

```
char Grade(int score)
{
    if(score >= 90) return 'A';
    else if(score >= 80) return 'B';
    else if(score >= 70) return 'C';
    else if(score >= 60) return 'D';
    return 'F';
}
```

Comment: Yes , that's precisely what was needed , besides with your patience you should also add a bit of explanation about your code :)

Answer (score 0):

As per other interpretations, changing a numerical grade from 100 to 50 into "A" to "F", where everything lower than 50 is an automatic "F", but now *without* any `if..else` statements. After all, it's a simple relation.

```
char Grade (int W)
{
   return W < 50 ? 'F' : 'F'-(W-50)/10;
}
```

There is a bit of rounding involved: everything from 90 to 100 will return "A", 80 to 89 will return "B", and so on.

(After considering your programmng level) A version without the ternary operator, which might make the logic clearer. Also removed about every possible build-in notation shortcut.

```
char Grade (int W)
{
   if (W < 50)
     return 'F';
   W = W-50; /* we know W >= 50 at this point */
   /* Now W=0..50 */
   W = W/10;
   /* Now W is 0..5 */
   return 'A'+5-W;
}
```